# AWS EC2 Instance IP not matching region

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ip

I instantiated a micro machine in the US-West(Oregon) region. For my application, I need to be  in Oregon - regulatory reasons. (The servers that my application will interact with will refuse connection otherwise.)

I tried curl ifconfig.me and searched the IP it produced. I was surprised that it returned

http://iplocation.truevue.org/50.112.44.39.html

Which seems to be in California. Is there a way to make sure that my IP is always originating from Oregon?

I looked into elastic IP, but that is for users connecting with the instance.

Appreciate thoughts greatly

Comment: IP geolocation isn't 100% accurate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a few Elastic IPs and test each one until you find one that appears to be in Oregon. Attach that Elastic IP address to the instance. If your initial set of five Elastic IPs don't satisfy your tests, release them, get more, and repeat until you have found one that does.

Your best bet is to use the Elastic IP address's DNS name (e.g. "ec2-50-112-33-39.us-west-2.aws.amazon.com") for communications. Services running within that region will get the instance's private IP address, minimizing the bandwidth usage charges, and services outside that region will get the elastic IP address that is internet-routable.

Answer (score 0):

Geo IP location is fragile and can't be fully trusted to determine host locations in the cloud.

I tested the IP of a Sydney region instance on http://www.iplocation.net/ and different services returned different countries: US, France, Australia.

If you need to be in Oregon for regulatory reasons and your partner service uses IP geolocation I would host with a company physically based in Oregon.

I think even elastic IP you might have the same issues where based on the geo IP service you get a different country. In general AWS IP will be registered by Amazon in Seattle.